# What is the name of this view that scrolls up when tap and hold image? iPhone

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, user-interface

On my iPhone app I am allowing the user to edit their profile picture.  When they press the edit button I want them to have the choice of either taking a picture, or getting an already existing image.  My question is not "How do I do that"  I'm sure there are other questions about that.  I know how I want to do it.  I want a small view to scroll up about halfway up the screen and let the user pick from the two options there.  I want it to look similar to the view on the iPhone when you tap and hold an image and a view scrolls up.  I'll attach an image.

So my question is, can I use some already existing functions to use that same scroll up view?  Or will I have to build it myself?  If it is existing, what is the name of it so I can find it somewhere here on SO?[image: I want my app to do this, can I reuse existing functions to implement this?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a `UIActionSheet`. See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/) for documentation.